# Having issues while building the jfrog artifacts. What type of changes I have to do in settings.xml or any permissions?

Tags: artifacts

I am having issues while building the jfrog artifacts. What type of changes do I have to do in settings.xml or any permissions?

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core/maven-metadata.xml from/to gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/34037247/packages/maven): status 

code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core/maven-metadata.xml from/to corporate-artifact-repository (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release): Connection refused (Connection refused)

[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core/maven-metadata.xml from/to corporate-snapshots-repository (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot): Connection refused (Connection refused)

[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations/maven-metadata.xml from/to gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/34037247/packages/maven): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
```

Comment: What is unclear to you about those 4 extremely clear errors?